# in Julia 0.6.4 how can we detect when reading a data file fails, on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: julia

Our .NET app periodically (10 times a second) writes to a status.txt file.
Our Julia 0.6.4 app reads this file.

If Julia reads it while .NET is writing it, our Julia app closes.

How can our Julia app detect that file is busy so app can loop and try again?

Update:
After adding routing stdout and stderr from Julia process
 to a file, the Julia process stopped closing.

Am concerned that continuous polling by Julia of the STATUS.txt may overrun the O.S.  (Win 10).  Inserted delay of 0.050 for each read.  The .NET app writes 9-10 times per second.

Comment: Does not [exception handling](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6/manual/control-flow/#The-try/catch-statement-1) help?

Comment: Thanks.  try … catch x  seems like what we need.  Will try/catch detect reading a file that is in use by another process?

Comment: `try...catch` will detect when an error/exception occurs and give you an opportunity to do something about it.

Comment: @DougNull I think that depends on your OS and how the other process (.NET app) opens the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are also "file events" in Julia, they seem to be done for your use case (e.g. wait for changes in a file)

Here is the documentation for Julia 1.0:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/FileWatching/index.html#FileWatching.watch_file

Here is the documentation for Julia 0.6.4:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6/stdlib/io-network/#Base.Filesystem.watch_file